# How to distort a shape in inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, shapes

How can I distort a shape so that it looks like it's drawn on the side of a cylinder? I.e. vertical lines should stay the same (just moving up or down depending on the location), and horizontal lines should become ellipse arcs.

Comment: @Dominic Thanks, but sketchup is not "free like Inkscape". If you're talking about 3D editors, Blender is "free like Inkscape" - available for Linux, open-source, and doesn't require filling some kind of registration form before downloading. Also, I would need an isometric/dimetric projection, and the result should be a 2D vector shape.

Comment: @Dominic Right now the shape I need is a triangle, like  the one on a play button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution at http://screencasters.heathenx.org/episode-088/ , using the Bezier Envelope extension by Gerrit Karius. I made an envelope with some beziers that approximate ellipse arcs, intersected with a rectangle, and after some fiddling, I managed to fit the shape to it using the extension.